# count records joining questions and answers tables

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables and would like to count solved questions:

**Table: questions**

```
id   title  solved_answer_id
174  Title1 0
172  Title2 45
173  Title3 0
175  Title4 49
```

**Table: answers**

```
id  created_by question_id
49  953        175
47  907        173
48  906        173 
46  907        172
45  906        172
```

May be someone know how to count solved questions (solved_answer_id>0) for answer created_by user: 953?

Thanks!

P.S Result will be: 1 for the case above (solved_answer_id = 49)...

Comment: =)) ok, if you say so...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select count(q.id) as cnt
from questions q
join answers a on a.question_id = q.id
where q.solved_answer_id > 0
and a.created_by = 953
```

Comment: Thank you very much! The snipped above really help me!